# Hive to BigQuery Converted INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE with PARTITION on Integer

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert the following Hive query to BigQuery with little luck. The idea is to remove the records from the specified partition and insert new records into the partition without touching other partitions. I have seen Google's documentation on using a DML statement to add rows to an ingestion-time partitioned table, but this isn't what I'm trying to accomplish.

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable PARTITION (integer_id = 100) select tmp.*, NULL as value from (select * from mytable2) as tmp;`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is already a `Feature Request` for this. You may refer to this https://issuetracker.google.com/113859346 . You may also `STAR` the feature request so that you can be notified regarding it and also `+1` to bring more attention on this request.